# Creating Object from Contents of Two Arrays

Tags: javascript, arrays, object

I have a situation where I need to format an object by combining information coming from two arrays. I've got the first part done, but I'm not sure how to generate the final object in the format I need.

First off I have an array of document changes that looks like this:

```
   [ { kind: 'E', path: ['short_name'], lhs: 'testing', rhs: 'testing1' },
     { kind: 'E', path: ['long_name'], lhs: 'testing', rhs: 'testing2' } ]
```

Then I have an array of mappings that looks like this:

```
[ { lhs: 'legacyId', rhs: 'id_number' },
  { lhs: 'name.short', rhs: 'short_name' },
  { lhs: 'name.long', rhs: 'long_name' } ]
```

Now, I match up values with the correct property names like so:

```
let p;
let v;
let combinedArray = [];

for (let diff of differences) {
  for (let mapping of mappings) {
    if (diff.path[0] === mapping.rhs) {
      p = diff.path[0];
      v = diff.rhs;
      combinedArray.push({ p, v });
    }
  }
}
```

This works and gives me this for `combinedArray`:

```
[ { p: 'short_name', v: 'testing1' },
  { p: 'payer_name', v: 'testing2' } ]
```

Now, the object I need to generate from this array needs to look like this:

```
{
  'short_name': 'testing1',
  'long_name': 'testing1'
}
```

How can I generate an object that looks like this from the contents of my `combinedArray`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could directly add the property to the object.

The you could take a `set` and omit the inner loop.

```js
var differences = [{ kind: 'E', path: ['short_name'], lhs: 'testing', rhs: 'testing1' }, { kind: 'E', path: ['long_name'], lhs: 'testing', rhs: 'testing2' }]
    mappings = [{ lhs: 'legacyId', rhs: 'id_number' }, { lhs: 'name.short', rhs: 'short_name' }, { lhs: 'name.long', rhs: 'long_name' }];
    rhs = new Set(mappings.map(({ rhs }) => rhs)),
    result = {};

for (let diff of differences) {
    if (rhs.has(diff.path[0])) {
        result[diff.path[0]] = diff.rhs;
    }
}

console.log(result);
```